# how to apply regex on _type field in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

```
{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 2,
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "index_name",
                "_type": "type_6831397832239852729",
                "_id": "a~~b~c~~d",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": { <Data>}
            },
            {
                "_index": "index_name",
                "_type": "type_-8642158362232960463",
                "_id": "a~~b~c~~d",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                <date>
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am having 2 documents under one index whose `_id` is same but `_type` is different. how can I apply regex on `_type` using java API?

eg :-  I want search where `_type=type_* and _id = a~~b~c~~d`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can just query it like a normal field.  I've put it in a query_string search here.

```
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":[  
            {  
               "query_string":{  
                  "query":"_type:type_*"
               }
            },
            {  
               "term":{  
                  "_id":"a~~b~c~~d"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: can  please let me know how to do it using java api ?

Comment: Can't sorry.  I actually stopped using the C# api because some functions weren't supported and it actually ended up taking more time than using JSON directly.